# Printing multidimensional array values

Tags: php

I have an array of this type, Using this code

```
$myarray = get_post_meta( $product->get_ID(), 'wcb2b_product_group_prices' );
print_r($myarray);
```

prints me:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [428] => Array ( [regular_price] => [sale_price] => ) [449] => Array ( [regular_price] => 20.00 [sale_price] => ) [9609] => Array ( [regular_price] => 20.00 [sale_price] => ) ) )
```

Updated code:

```
$myarray = get_post_meta( $product->get_ID(), 'wcb2b_product_group_prices' );

//print_r($myarray);
 
foreach ($myarray as $key => $value) {
    // print_r($value);
    foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
        // print_r($value2);
        foreach ($value2 as $key3 => $value3) {
            echo $value3;
        }
    }
}
```

I would be able to print the [regular_price][sale_price] Value.

How do you do that?

Thanks for help

Comment: what have you done so far ?

Comment: Looking at the `wcb2b` plugin (https://woocommerce-b2b.com/) it looks like you've defined prices per customer group (`428`, `449` and `9609`). So are you looking to display the prices for the current user group or display all prices for all groups?

Comment: The prices for all groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should do what you're looking for...

```php
if ( $group_prices = get_post_meta( $product->get_ID(), 'wcb2b_product_group_prices', true ) ) {
    foreach ( $group_prices as $group => $group_price ) {
        $regular_price = $group_price[ 'regular_price' ] ?? null;
        $sale_price = $group_price[ 'sale_price' ] ?? null;

        if ( $regular_price ) {
            echo '<strong>Regular price for group ' . $group . ':</strong> ' . wc_price( $regular_price ) . '<br>';
        }
        
        if ( $sale_price ) {
            echo '<strong>Sale price for group ' . $group . ':</strong> ' . wc_price( $sale_price ) . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

This will output something like...

```html
<strong>Regular price for group 449:</strong> $20.00<br>
<strong>Regular price for group 9609:</strong> $20.00<br>
```

1. First we set the 3rd parameter for `get_post_meta` to `true` which removes the first level of the array which is unnecessary.
2. We then loop through the groups and get regular and sale prices for each group, checking if they have values before printing.
3. Finally, we print the price using the WooCommerce core [`wc_price()`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-formatting-functions.html#function_wc_price) function which will format the price value with the currency symbol.